# Parse: "containedIn" returns nothing if I used it with pointer type

Tags: javascript, mongodb, parse-platform, back4app, dbaas

If I try to filter the data by using `containedIn` as below I will be getting empty result because I'm trying to filter from pointer column type `userProfile` despite that I include the `userProfile` in the query.

However, I tried to use `containedIn` directly to another array column in `User` and seems it was working fine. is this kind of the below queries will not work? and what could be the alternative solutions?

```
const query = new Parse.Query('User');
query.equalTo('accountType', 'Student');
query.include('userProfile');

// search.subjects is an array
query.containedIn('userProfile.subjectsIds', search.subjects);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't perform containedIn() on included objects. For containedIn() to work it has to be performed on a column of the class you are querying.

So in other words, you will have to perform this query directly on the **userProfile** class for containedIn() to work

Answer (score 0):

A "little bit" late, but it is absolutely possible. To see examples using query (like you want to), have a look here, starting on line 595:

https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/80b987d00d8eda89f1ee521103c4737b64c66cc1/spec/QueryTools.spec.js#L630

Easiest way of finding examples is going through tests in the parse repo, at least for me.

If you want to do this in the aggregation pipeline, just use $match stage with $in, like below, where *<column_name>* is the name of the pointer column, *ids* is an array of ids and *table_name* is the table you point to. The $ sign and _p_ are there because of how parse works and are necessary.

```
{
    $match: {
        _p_<column_name>: { "$in": ids.map((id) =>  "table_name$"+id)}
    }
}
```

I think it is also very instructive to play with MongoDB console.